# Streaming live audio from Wowza to HTML5 clients?

Tags: html, wowza

I have an existing app that streams live audio from a Flash client over RTMP to a Wowza zerver ... I am able to connect Flash clients to this and get real-time, low latency audio without problem.

I'd like to connect some HTML5 based clients in PC, Android and iOS and not use any Flash on the client side ... the RTMP URI is normally "rtmp://myserver/live/mystream"  I've tried connecting video and audio tags from HTML5 pages with no success.

Wowza sells on the basis of being able to stream to any client ... if anyone knows the magic URI to put into an HTML video/audio tag, or some other method to allow me to receive the stream without suing Flash in the browser, I'd be very interested to see them.

Please note: this is live audio from an RTMP source, not files. It is audio, not video.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use HLS for playback. The URI is in the form

```
http://<wowzaIP>:1935/<appName>/<streamName>/playlist.m3u8
```

Moreover, Wowza currently supports HTML5 playback with the video tag for Safari on OSX/iOS devices only. Other browsers/platforms may be possible, but results vary. Alternatively, you can look into using an HTML5 player such as the free Wowza Player, and it should work across platforms.

Comment: I had already tried this on my laptop with Firefox, sadly, it doesn't work, I used '<video controls="controls" src="http://myserver:1935/myapp/demo/playlist.m3u8">
</video>'  and all I get is a video (which since I want only the audio is a bit odd, but whatever) with a warning about "MIME type not supported"

Comment: What platform are you using, and which version of Firefox? Also, does the HLS stream work when using with an HTML5 player such as Wowza Player?